# Add correctly positioned layers to context

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I'm trying to add two CALayers from a UIImageView and UITextField to a context, then create an image from the context using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, however, I can't seem to position the text field correctly. I'd like the resulting image to match the view in which the image and text field originally appear. Instead, the text field appears half hidden beyond the top of the image. Currently, I'm trying something like this (which is wrong):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let ht = self.imageView.bounds.size.height
let wdth = self.imageView.bounds.size.width
self.imageView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)

CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, self.imageView.center.x, self.imageView.center.y)
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, self.imageView.transform)
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -wdth * self.imageView.layer.anchorPoint.x, -ht * self.imageView.layer.anchorPoint.y)
// Set points for text label here, then...
self.textLabelTop.layer.renderInContext(ctx)

let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return newImage
```

I understand `CGContextTranslateCTM()` and `CTContextConcatCTM()` have to do with applying the original coordinate system onto the context, then placing the layer, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly. Could someone provide an example of the proper technique?

**Update:** This seems like a hack, but instead of translating the points to the context, if I simply add the text field as a subview of the UIImageView after editing and before `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, things seem to work, including with the placement of a second text field:

```
self.imageView.addSubview(self.textLabelTop)
self.imageView.addSubview(self.textLabelBottom)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
self.imageView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)          
let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return newImage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of `convertPoint:toView:` possible. try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
self.imageView.layer.renderInContext(ctx)

let point = self.textLabelTop.superview!.convertPoint(self.textLabelTop.frame.origin, toView: self.imageView)
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, point.x, point.y)
self.textLabelTop.layer.renderInContext(ctx)

let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return newImage
```